# horizontal and vertical lines in UI of an iphone application

Tags: iphone, line

How can I place horizontal and vertical lines in my UI of an iphone application?
Is it possible in xib? Can any one give me an idea?
Is there any source code available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 basic approaches:

1. Use QuartzCore and override drawRect: in a custom UIView subclass
2. Set the borderWidth and borderColor of the UIView layer
   property that contains each image
3. Create UIViews of height 1 for horizontal lines and width 1 for
   vertical lines, set the backgroundColor of the views and add them as
   subviews

3 is probably the easiest to implement, but not the most elegant, 1 is the most robust in terms of memory as you can also use drawInRect to draw your images into the same graphics context. This collapses the view hierarchy into a single view.

Answer (score 0):

You may put a view of a single line width or height and make its background colour as line colour you want.